# What is the role of handler.py in App Engine bulk upload/download?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was reading the Google App Engine tutorial for [bulk upload/download](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html). Could somebody please tell me what is the role of the script : 'handler.py' that has to be specified in the app.yaml file ? The documentation does not specifically talk about the role of this script.

Answer (score 1):

In the remote_api the handler.py is the script that will let locally executing python code access the remote app's datastore (after you've provided administrator authentication).  Bulk loader needs it to push and pull data to/from your datastore.

I recommend using the `builtins` directive instead of adding that entry to your app.yaml

Comment: So the code in handler.py runs on the client side and facilitates RPC calls to bulk upload / download data ? Oh, and why do you want me to use the builtins directive ?

Comment: Other way around. Handler.py lives on the server and receives the RPC calls from bulkloader.py or remote_api_shell.py, which run client-side.

Comment: I recommend the builtins directive because it's supposedly future-proof. If google moved/changed handler.py in the future builtins would continue to work, but the app.yaml usage would probably break.